# Google Cloud Kubernetes with HTTP LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, load-balancing

I have a web app in docker container that i want to deploy in google cloud,
and I am following this documentation to deploy my app https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#exposing_the_sample_app_to_the_internet.

This particular step to expose the app using load balancer works and it gives a public ip and I am able to access my app as well. But the problem is I want to use a domain for this app with https. The loadbalancer that got deployed is a TCP loadbalancer.

Playing around with the loadbalancer settings in the console I see Https Loadbalancer has an option to attach ssl certificate. But I couldnt find a way to expose my app to this HTTPs loadbalancer.
Are there any step by step documentation tutorials to do this ?
Is this possible with a TCP loadbalancer too i.e an https web app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detailed step by step documentation you can refer to this link 
[Configuring Ingress for external load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress)

Steps summary are:

1. Creating Deployment
2. Creating Service
3. Creating Ingress
4. Testing the External HTTP(S) Load Balancer.

See below links for other document reference. Below sites will help you on the other areas using SSL Certficates. GKE load balancing and TCP Configuration.

[Using Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) 
SSL certificates with Kubernetes Engine, see [HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)  
[Configuring TCP/UDP Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters)